# Not able to make connection with HP ALM 12.53 using excel macro

Tags: excel, alm, vba

I am using the below code to connect to ALM 12.53 but not able to, getting error message:

> Active X can't create object

```
Private Sub BtnAuthenticate_Click()
    errmsg = "No Error"
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    Set tdc = CreateObject("tdapiole80.TDconnection")
    MsgBox ("Connect to QC Server")
    Set WSConfig = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALM Express")
    If tdc.Connected Then
        Set tdc = Nothing
    End If
    tdc.InitConnectionEx (Trim(WSConfig.Cells(3, 6).Value))
    Strusrnme = WorksheetFunction.Trim(TxtUserID.Text)
    strpwd = TxtPWD.Text
    errmsg = "Authentication failed. verify your UserID and Password"
    tdc.Login Strusrnme, strpwd
    '...
End Sub
```

Although i have successfully installed HP ALM Connectivity Tool Add-in and can see that the folder created "Mercury Interactive" in my c-drive.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Mercury Interactive

Comment: Is there a library/reference you're supposed to add?

Comment: i think i have already each and every library/reference which needs to be added for this connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be more clear with further information, but perhaps you need the **ALM Explorer Add-In**?

> ALM Explorer Add-In is useful if you are unable to download ActiveX controls or if your browser restricts the use of *ActiveX* components. The only components that are downloaded when you use ALM Explorer are ALM components.
>
> **Note:** ALM Explorer does not support Performance Center windows, such as the Performance Test Designer, Performance Trending, or MyPC. These windows open in a standard Web browser.

([**Source**](https://marketplace.microfocus.com/appdelivery/content/alm-explorer-add))

Comment: By downgrading to excel version 2010, resolves the issue. Thanks @ashleedawg for your reply.